# How to get JavaFX working on Mac OS (applet on Firefox)?

Tags: java, macos, firefox

I have recently used migration assistant to restore an old image onto a new Macbook but now a JavaFX applet that I use is no longer working. Since then, I have I have reinstalled java (both JRE and SDK) and firefox. I have also adjusted the security settings and made sure firefox is running on 64bit. I am at a loss. Can anyone please help?

The exact error message is: JavaFX2.0 is required to view this content but JavaFX is currently unsupported on this platform

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences, **JavaFX 2.0 doesn't work on Mac OS with Java 1.6.** But it worked on Windows.  I upgraded to Java 1.7 on Mac OS, but JavaFX 2.0 didn't work. Java 1.7 has JavaFX in its own library but couldn't recognize both JavaFX 2.0 and JavaFX inside Java 1.7 library. Finally I upgraded to Java 1.8 on Mac OS and it worked. However, I had to change all the legacy code.